# Should I use "ser" or "estar" for dyed hair?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, cópulas

So I'm doing Duolingo and I just reviewed the To Be section and they had many examples of phrases similar to

> He is blonde / Él **es** rubio

This makes sense to me as someone is intrinsically "naturally blonde". I do however, wonder, if someone dyes his hair blonde, do we say

> Él **está** rubio

to show that it's temporary?

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta debería responderla @Rubio ... Ric :P

Comment: We would use another verb: _Él *va de* rubio_.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Yo también lo había pensado XD Pero es mi apellido no mi color de pelo ;-P Yo soy Rubio.

Comment: Off topic.  I have heard estar de soltero as a rough equivalent of batching it.

Answer (score 1):

No, if someone dyes their hair, "es" is still used.

> Mi amiga se ha teñido el pelo. Ahora **es** pelirroja.
> // My friend has dyed her hair. Now she's redhead.

There is no distinction. If you dye your hair, that's your new color now.

> Antes de teñirme el pelo, yo **era** rubio.
> // Before I dyed my hair, I was blonde.

*Era = imperfect tense of Ser.*

Answer (score 0):

In the phrase "he is blonde", is indicates the current state of his hair. If he dyes it, you could say "he's now redheaded" (ya es pelirrojo) or "he went redhead" (se volvió pelirrojo), but you don't point to the dying process every time you refer to his hair in the future. You can explicitly say "he used to be dark haired" or similar, but otherwise you just change the color itself: "he is deal haired/redheaded/etc". It's the same in spanish.